# Console does not refresh after creating servlet in Eclipse - Juno

Tags: java, eclipse

I have

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Juno Service Release 1
Build id: 20120920-0800
```

I had created a basic

```
public class T1 {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Hello World");
}

}
```

which was working fine.

However, as soon as I created another Dynamic Web Project and now go back to run this previous program with any new output instead of the "Hello World",  the console still ends up printing the same old `Hello World`

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: have you tried restarting the server?

Comment: It shows up once I refresh. But the thing is , I am using  a basic java project to write a core java application. Why does it depend on the Tomcat Server? Restarting the tomcat server each time for the core java application will get tedious. Do you recommend using a seperate editor for core java projects ?

Comment: Have you tried running the app again now without restarting and changing the sysout message? Does it require a server restart before the sysout message updates?

Comment: Who is calling this main method .. in web application?? It will not be called itself..  and if its a core java application then why u should use web perspective.

Comment: I realized that the file was not being saved before running it. Once the file is saved and then run, the changes carry over to the console.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the configuration file in Web server. In case of tomcat its installDirectory/conf/server.xml .. check your server documentation to know the file. Check the DefaultContext element, Its reloadable attribute should be set to true,.. I feel its not configured correctly.

This will help you to automatically reload the servlet and jsp after recompiling it whenever the code changes.